# Java disutil CoordinateConversions import problems

Tags: java, import, compiler-errors, coordinate

I'm writing a Java class that will be used to send PDUs across a network- to do this, I am following the tutorial at: [Tutorial](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/edu.nps.moves/open-dis/4.08/edu/nps/moves/examples/EspduSender.java)

In the example, the line:

```
double lla[] = CoordinateConversions.xyzToLatLonDegrees(c);
```

appears towards the end of the class, and I see that `CoordinateConversions` has been imported with the line:

```
import edu.nps.moves.disutil.CoordinateConversions;
```

I have tried using the `xyzToLatLonDegrees();` method in the class that I am writing- calling it in the same way as is done in the example. However, for some reason, I get a compile error that says:

> CoordinateConversions cannot be resolved

on the line where I'm trying to use it, and

> The import edu.nps.moves.disutil.CoordinateConversions cannot be resolved

on the line where I am importing it.

Does anyone know why this is, and how I can fix the import, so that I can use the `xyzToLatLonDegrees()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `CoordinateConversions` class on your classpath. Either by obtaining the source and dropping it into your project (possibly adjusting package names, and only if the license allows), or by finding a JAR containing that class and adding it to your build path in your IDE.

You probably need to download the Java files from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-dis/files/open-dis/).

Comment: Thanks- it seems that the program I'm working on was using an old version on the open-dis library, so that's why it wasn't there...

Comment: Follow on question- having updated the version of the open-dis library that I was using to the current version, that cleared up the original error. However, I'm now getting a compile error on the `package` statement, above the imports in a couple of my classes. This says things like: `The type javax.persistence.GenerationType cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`.... I had look on Google about this, but can't find anything that helps... any suggestions why I'm getting these errors with the package?